# Преобразование числа в строку и отправка его в LPARAM

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть массив случайных чисел, числа нужно отправить в listbox. Как известно, числовые значения он не принимает, только строковые. Пытаюсь преобразовать массив чисел в массив строк и затем отправит в LPARAM. Как итог в listbox абракадбра полная, что делаю не так?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    mas[i] = rand() % 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::stringstream s[10];
    s[i] << mas[i];
    SendMessage(hList1, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, LPARAM((&s[i].str())));
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может приложите скришнот того, что получается, что бы легче было гадать? но думаю, что вся проблема в том, что Listbox ожидает двухбайтовый юникод, а ему дают однобайтовое аскии.

Comment: Прикрепил, если Вы правы, то как правильно ему послать строку?

Comment: попробовать заменить `std::stringstream` на `std::wstringstream`.

Comment: Еще есть проблема, что надо посылать C-строку, а не указатель на std::string.

Comment: Массив строковых потоков в цикле совершенно не нужен.

Comment: @dzhioev это точно. Надо бы `s[i].str().c_str()` скорее всего.

Comment: std::wstringstream не помог, выводи абракадабру немного другого вида

Так я указатель и не посылаю, а по адресу строку вроде как?

Comment: Адрес от `std::string` это не `const char*`, если Вы так подумали.

Comment: Всё ребят, сделал `std::wstringstream` и `s[i].str().c_str()` и всё заработало. Огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: @KoVadim, правильнее будет сделать `typedef std::stringstream MyStream` или `typedef std::wstringstream MyStream` в зависимости от того, defined ли UNICODE, и везде использовать MyStream.

Comment: В идеале конечно, хотелось бы знать, почему `std::wstringstream`, а не `std::stringstream` и что такое `c_str()`

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков теперь можете добавить решение в качестве ответа на свой же вопрос. Для внесения, так сказать, своего вклада в развитие SO по-русски. Ещё и карму поднимите себе :)

Comment: Как это сделать ?) И да, я, если честно, не совсем понял почему это работает)) Я вот выше чуть спросил, может ответит кто)

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков а у Вас нет поля типа "добавить свой ответ"? Может быть это ограничение из-за недостаточной "кармы". Не могу подсказать, к сожалению. Работает, потому что **должно** :) По классам стандартной библиотеки см.описание. Например, [тут](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/).

Comment: @alexolut Всё, готово) А почему люди, которые помогли мне, не сделали это как ответ на данный вопрос ?)

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков за всех ответить не могу, но мне было лень :) На самом деле, просто код, который я не могу проверить сам, предпочитаю не размещать. Ну и решение родилось в обсуждении, т.о. авторство тоже присваивать себе не хочу.

Answer (score 1):

`std::stringstream` заменить на `std::wstringstream` и `LPARAM((&s[i].str()))` заменить на `LPARAM((s[i].str().c_str()))`

Comment: Зачем вы массив из 10 stringstream-ов заводите на каждой итерации?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Могу предложить вариант (***если остальное не помогает***)

- Создать `static` переменную типа `char *` в `WNDPROC`.
- Значения заполнять с помощью `itoa(char,int,int)` в цикле.
- Выводить `static char*` строку.